# Beamer: label ref wrong display format

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I am having trouble with the format of the referenced subsection in Beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}\label{subsec:mysubsection}
\begin{frame}
\ref{subsec:mysubsection} % displayed as 1 , but should be 1.1
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In Beamer article output it is as excepeted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\begin{document}
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}\label{subsec:mysubsection}
\begin{frame}
\ref{subsec:mysubsection} % displayed ok as 1.1
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What do I have to do, that the reference is displayed in Beamer mode as $sectionnumber.$subsectionnumber ?

Comment: `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}` (this can affect other places where the number is used).

Answer (score 2):

A simple redefinition of `\thesubsection` does the trick:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}

\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{mysection}
\subsection{mysubsection}\label{subsec:mysubsection}
\begin{frame}
\ref{subsec:mysubsection}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the section number should only appear in references, but `\thesubsection` should not be changed, then `\p@subsection` defines a prefix for the references:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{p@subsection}{\thesection.}
\@namedef{p@subsubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}.}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following instructions to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{subsection}{section}
```